# HTML PHP put a cell under a specific header according to query

Tags: php, html

I have various tasks under various departments. The department name and id come as table header (`<th>`). I have displayed them.

Now I query the tasks and if the task belongs Dept A I want it under `<th id='A'>` and if task belogs to Dept B it should be under `<th id='B'>`.

My problem is that some depts may  not have task for this particular row and so that cell should be empty. The next cell may have value. So how to tell html to put an empty cell when necessary ie, I want to do something like this:

```
if(th id == 'DeptA' and resultSet.deptId = 'DeptA') 
        then <td> resultSet(i); </td>
else <td> </td>
```

I am a bit new to HTML and PHP. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
foreach(...){
  echo '<tr><td>';
  if(th id == 'DeptA' && resultSet.deptId == 'DeptA'){
    echo resultSet(i);
  }
  echo '</td><td>';
  if(th id == 'DeptB' && resultSet.deptId == 'DeptB'){
    echo resultSet(i);
  }
  echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

`<table>` - starts the table
`<tr>` - is a table row
`<td>` - is a table column

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of variable you are referencing with "th id".  Also you need to setup the "for" or "foreach" statement correctly and reference those variables correctly later in the code.